# Microsoft Graph API Batch Request Throttling (Graph SDK)

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

I have been working on sending multiple batch requests to Microsoft Graph using Graph SDK.

I have following questions for which I could not find answers through the documentation.

1. Is batch request considered a single request request? Or the individual requests are considered separately? For example: I want to remove members from the group, so I create a batch request that consists of 19 individual requests to remove different members. Will that batch request be counted as 1 request or 19 requests?
2. I understand that Graph SDK has a default retry-handler that is capable of handling 429 response. But how does does that work with **Batch requests** ?
3. Do batch requests help at all in not getting throttled?
4. If the individual request gets throttled, will the Graph SDK try to handle 429 response for individual requests?

APIs that I am working on include updating team members (add, remove)

Any suggestion or useful information will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Requests in batches are individually evaluated against throttling limits
2. Requests in batches are not retried by the dotnet SDK if they fail with a 429 response. [See the code](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-core/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Graph.Core/Requests/Content/BatchResponseContent.cs)
3. They help for global service protections: the number of parallel HTTP connections and HTTP requests rates for a given application.
4. See response #2